# How can we derive the equations?

Tags: geometry, vectors

This is an excerpt from the book [Curves and Surfaces for Computer Graphics](http://www.davidsalomon.name/CaS/CaS.html).

[image]

How did the author derive $ \alpha $ and $ \beta $?

Answer (score 1):

$\alpha\ \mathbf{A} + \beta\ \mathbf{B} + \mathbf{C} = 0$ is nothing but a system of two equations, one for each component $x$ and $y$:
$$
\cases{
\alpha {A_x} + \beta B_x + C_x = 0&\cr
\alpha {A_y} + \beta B_y + C_y = 0&\cr
}
$$
 One can solve it with a variety of well known methods.

Comment: Looks like [Cramer’s rule](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/solving-systems-of-equations-using-determinants-cr.html) might have been used to solve the system.

Comment: @amd Cramer's rule is fine, but even a straightforward substitution method (find $\alpha$ from the first equation and plug result into the second) is manageable.

Comment: True. Cramer’s rule came to mind because the numerators and denominators look like 2x2 determinants, but vector cross products as in Chinny84’s answer would also produce expressions of that form.

Comment: I like the simplicity! +1

Answer (score 1):

$$
\alpha \mathbf{A} + \beta \mathbf{B} = -\mathbf{C}
$$
Knowing that the vector cross product of parallel vectors leads to zero so
$$
\alpha \mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B} = -\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{B}
$$ thus we get
$$
\alpha = -\frac{\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{B}}{\mathbf{A}\times \mathbf{B}}
$$
And similarly 
$$
\beta = -\frac{\mathbf{C}\times \mathbf{A}}{\mathbf{B}\times \mathbf{A}}
$$
Do you need me to go over the products?

Comment: This is pretty much how you’d do it using homogeneous coordinates. The line through two points is given by the cross product of those points, and the point of intersection of two lines is given by their cross product.

Comment: Yup you are right about the coordinate system! I have used this many times when working with systems of vector partial differential equations.